# Must you create the .m2/repository folder manually

Tags: maven

Will the `.m2` folder be created automatically by Maven, or do you need to create it manually?

What does the `.m2/repository`, contain and from where does it come?

Comment: Might have been quicker to find out by installing Maven and running something simple.

Answer (score 18):

First, it will be created by Maven when you execute a build, such as:

```
mvn clean install
```

Note, you could find this out just be executing mvn your self ;)

Second, the contents of .m2 are:

A `settings.xml` file that contains global settings for all maven executions.

A folder called `repository` that holds all of the local copies of various maven artifacts, either caches of artifacts pulled down from remote repositories, such as Maven Central, or artifacts built by your local maven builds.  The artifacts are organized in there in folder structures that mirror the groupId's of the artifacts.

Comment: actually u just create a maven project it will try to create a ~/.m2/ +1 for u

Answer (score 12):

It will be created automatically. The repository folder (also called **local repository**) will download its content from repositories specified in your **user's** `settings.xml`, the **global** `settings.xml` and possibly in your poms.

Most artifacts will be downloaded from `repo1.maven.org`.